# Esperar servlet concluir ação, e atualizar tela com js

Tags: javascript, servlet

Eu passo um valor para a servlet, com js, para nao redirecionar a página:

```
      var formData = new FormData();
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
      xhr.open('POST', 'ServletMessage', true);
       xhr.send(formData);
```

e gravo esse valor no banco de dados, o problema é que a página atualiza antes de gravar no bd, e o valor nao muda na tela. Como posso esperar a servlet gravar no banco, e depois a página atualizar?

Answer (score 1):

É necessário definir uma função pra tratar o evento [`XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange). Esse evento é acionado sempre que o estado do pedido for alterado. Pra fazer alguma coisa quando o pedido terminar (estado `XMLHttpRequest.DONE`), fazemos algo assim:

```
var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
var postData = 'nome=' + encodeURIComponent(nome);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open('POST', 'ServletMessage', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200)
            console.log('Pedido concluído com sucesso, atualize a página');
        else
            console.log('Erro');
    }
};

xhr.send(postData);
```

Comment: Como eu faço pra receber esse valor na servlet, por exemplo um campo de texto? estou tentando, mas sempre vem null.

Comment: Modifiquei minha resposta incluindo um exemplo. No seu código, `formData` era inicializado mas era enviado sem definir valor nenhum.

Comment: Como eu faço pra chamar essa função? e eu posso adicionar um array de files?

Comment: Pra anexar um arquivo costuma-se usar `FormData` mesmo. Pra usar esse _bloco de código_, você tem que criar a função primeiro. A partir daí, você especifica a função no evento de um elemento diretamente ou usa o [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener) (recomendado).